# Почему не загружаются файлы на сервер больше 7кб?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, upload, filestream

Использую Ruby on Rails, Apache. Столкнулся с проблемой загрузки файла на сервер. Читал подобные статьи здесь же, но не помогло, либо руки не из того места растут. Использую обычную форму для отправки `<%= f.file_field :path %>` и контроллер:

```
def upload
  uploaded_io = params[:article][:path]
  File.open(Rails.root.join('public','uploads',uploaded_io.original_filename,'wb') do |file|
    file.write(uploaded_io.read)
  end
end
```

При этом есть `params.require(:article).permit(:path)`

Вопрос в том, почему не загружаются файлы больше 7кб? Ясно, что больше файл 7—10Кб хранится как поток, но как его обработать? При попытке загрузить файл больше 7кб выдаёт 500 ошибка скрипта cgi, а при размерах до 7кб всё хорошо. Прошу помощи в объяснении. И откуда взялось такое ограничение в 7кб?

---

Лог ошибки:"Unexpected error in mod_passenger: An error occured while buffering HTTP upload data to a temporary file in /tmp/passenger.1.0.965717/generation-163/buffered_uploads. The current Apache worker process doesn't have permissions to write to this directory. Please change the permissions for this directory so that it is writable by the Apache worker process, or set the 'PassengerUploadBufferDir' directive to a directory that Apache can write to."
Недостаточно прав для записи в папку-буфер passengera.

Comment: 500-ая ошибка это обычно непойманный Exception, найдите в логах более конкретное описание.

Comment: Из вопроса совершенно непонятно, как сделать такой вывод. Отредактируете, чтобы можно было оставить обоснованный ответ? Или закрываем по "не воспроизводится/опечатка"?

Comment: Ошибка была в правах доступа к буферной папке Passenger.
"Unexpected error in mod_passenger: An error occured while buffering HTTP upload data to a temporary file in /tmp/passenger.1.0.965717/generation-163/buffered_uploads. The current Apache worker process doesn't have permissions to write to this directory. Please change the permissions for this directory so that it is writable by the Apache worker process, or set the 'PassengerUploadBufferDir' directive to a directory that
Apache can write to." Указал PassengerUploadBufferDir в .htaccess и все заработало.

Comment: Неплохо. Добавьте это сообщение в вопрос и напишите ответ.

Comment: Нет, не так. В сообщение добавьте что было в логах, а ответ отдельно.

Comment: Нет, не так. Ответ нужно писать в соответствующем поле.

Answer (score 1):

Решение: Изменить права доступа в стандартной папке, либо указать на другую папку с возможностью 'rw'. Изменить PassengerUploadBufferDir в .htaccess.